# How to get the display in language for browser jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am able to get the "display in language" using jquery. but is there any way by which i can get "Display in Language" using jquery.

To get the preferred language, we can use below code:

```js
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
alert("The language is: " + userLang);
```

I tried to find this on google but 99% posts show how to get the prefered language. but I need to get "Display in Language". Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *I am able to get the "display in language" using jquery. but is there any way by which i can get "Display in Language" using jquery.* Explain it.

Comment: @iNullPointer, check the chrome language settings, you will get what i mean. :)